# How to create a property for the property from parent class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I set a property attribution from child class to a property attribution of parent class? for attribution, I know I can do something like
`setattr(self.name, 'nickname', object)`. However, if I have one class like Animal that is inherited by Bird and include one property called name. Is it possible for me to create another property
under name for class Bird?

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = None
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

class Bird(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    # I need to create the other property under name attribution from Animal class as nickname
    #so I can access as cat.name.nickname = 'i am nickname'
    #print(cat.name.nickname) # 'i am nickname
    #@property
    #def nickname(self):
    #    return self._name
    #
    #@name.setter
    #def name(self, value):
    #    self._name = value
cat = Animal()
cat.name = 'i am cat'
print(cat.name) # i am cat
```

Comment: Note, that would be a poor design - to implicitly effect/modify Base class from derived class (child class)

Answer (score 0):

Properties getters and setters can call the property methods on the superclass, with super -

This mean you can recreate the `name` property in the subclass, retrieve the super-class value, for compatibility, and wrap it on another class, which has the attributes you want.

However, the key `_name` would be taken in the instance dictionary to keep the value `Animal.name` property knows about - so we need another shadow name in the instance to keep the values for exclusive of the subclass.

That said, it is still needed to build a clever class that can wrap the original value of the property on the superclass, and know how to handle attribute setting and retrieval on the subclass - the `Wrapper` code bellow can do that:

```
class Wrapper(str):
    def __new__(cls, original_str, *args):
        return super().__new__(cls, original_str)
    def __init__(self, original_str, name_in_parent, parent):
        self._name = name_in_parent
        self._parent = parent

        # original_str is taken care of in `__new__`
    def __setattr__(self, attrname, value):
        if attrname.startswith("_"):
            return super().__setattr__(attrname, value)
        ns = getattr(self._parent, self._name, None)
        if ns is None:
            ns = {}
            setattr(self._parent, self._name, ns)
        ns[attrname] = value
    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        return getattr(self._parent, self._name)[attrname]
```

And this will work with a simple property on the superclass like:

```
class Animal:
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        # just so that the property is not 100% meaningless
        self._name = value.lower()

class Bird(Animal):
    @property 
    def name(self):
        return Wrapper(super().name, "_bird_name", self)
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        # this turned out to be the trickiest part - to retrieve
        # the original property on the superclass so that we can 
        # call it's setter. `super()` did not work for this.
        # We set just the core value - the specialized class
        # with more attributes is only used upon reading the property back
        super_property = [getattr(val, "name")  for val in a.__class__.__mro__[1:] if hasattr(val, "name")][0]
        super_property.__set__(self, value)
```

And this working:

```
In [511]: b = Bird()                                                                                                              

In [512]: b.name = "Woodpecker"                                                                                                  

In [513]: b.name                                                                                                                  
Out[513]: 'woodpecker'

In [514]: b.name.nickname = "Woody"                                                                                               

In [515]: b.__dict__                                                                                                              
Out[515]: {'_name': 'woodpecker', '_bird_name': {'nickname': 'Woody'}}

In [516]: b.name.nickname                                                                                                         
Out[516]: 'Woody'
```

If you want to restrict the accepted sub-attributes, just use plain `if` statements in `Wrapper.__setattr__`.